# Create nXn matrix with values incrementing Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, matrix

Im trying to find an easy way to create matrix with self incrementing values i.e., if 3x3 array then it should look like
[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

when I do something like below, I could get all zero's

```
var arr = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 3), count: 3)
```

Inorder to acheive, I need to loop through elements and reassign incremented values. Instead of that is there any fast approach I could follow without using for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to use `map()` on the range of rows and columns:

```
let nrows = 3 // Number of rows
let ncols = 3 // Number of columns
let matrix = (0..<nrows).map { row in (0..<ncols).map { col in ncols * row + col } }
print(matrix) // [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

The outer `(0..<nrows).map` maps each row number to an array (the “row”), and the inner `(0..<ncols).map` maps each column number to a matrix entry.

With a little bit “tuple magic” you could assign auto-incrementing values:

```
var entry = 0
let matrix = (0..<nrows).map { _ in (0..<ncols).map { _ in (entry, entry += 1).0 } }
```

but that's not what I would really recommend.

Answer (score 0):

There is the a [Subscripts](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html) tutorial on Swift.org showing a Matrix struct example, which I really like